# jQuery manually slider in two rows

Tags: jquery, html

Learning jQuery by building a slider. My intention is to make two rows of pictures that will slide by width of one pictures on left or right depend on button click. Also, I'd like slider to be endless.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L590q2ct/7/ (note: working on the "next" button)

My jQuery is below:

```
$('#next').click(function() {
var first = $('.slide').eq(0);
var count = $('.slide').length;
var last = $('.slide').eq(count-1);
var width = $('.slide').width();

first.addClass('active');

var slide = function() {
    target = $('.active').index();
    target === last.index() ? target = 0 : target = target+1; //target won't increse
    nextSlide(target);
    console.log(target)
}

var nextSlide = function(target) {
    $('#top').animate({'left': '-' + width + 'px'},300);  //moving target picture to the left
    $('.slide').removeClass('active').eq(target).addClass('active');
}

slide();
});
```

I'm facing these problems:

1. target slide won't get increased so I can't add "active" class to the next one
2. Can't figured out how to put first picture on last place when button is clicked.

Any advice is welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem that you are doing, is that you are setting the `first` element to be the `active` one every time you click on the next button, that's why the target never changes.

the second thing is that you set the `margin-left` every time with the width of the image, while you should shift it by `target*width` to match which element should be shown.

```
var first = $('.slide').eq(0);
var count = $('.slide').length;
var last = $('.slide').eq(count - 1);
var width = $('.slide').width();
first.addClass('active');

$('#next').click(function() {
  var slide = function() {
    target = $('.active').index();
    target = target === count-1 ?  0 : target + 1;      
    nextSlide(target);
        console.log(target)
  }

  var nextSlide = function(target) {
    $('#top').animate({
      'margin-left': '-' + target*width + 'px'
    }, 300);
    $('.slide').removeClass('active').eq(target).addClass('active');
  }

  slide();

});
```

here is a [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Aya_Salama/jwetdpm4/)

Comment: Thank you, but how can I get pictures, that are out of viewport, to be set on the end of row? In other words, intend  to make endless sliding so there's no "empty spaces"  when sliding is occurred.

Comment: the problem of empty slides is because you are counting all the `.slide` elements which are 9 and change the position only to the `top` div, why did you separate the images in 2 different divs?

Comment: First idea was to slide both divs on one click. Therefor I divided it to two parts. Now when your saying, I'll think about puting all imgs in one div and use flex-wrap. Suggestion? Thank you Aya!

Comment: change it in and put all in one div with flex-wrap: http://jsfiddle.net/Ld1a20vu/7/ . I'll be very greatful if you'll give me some hint how to put picture out of viewport back to end of the row.

Comment: I'm still not sure why do you want it in 2 rows or more?
 usually, the slider should show 1 image per time, and you don't need to put the image back in the row, cause you already made a condition to start from the beginning once it reaches the last element.
here is a demo for what I mean, but not sure if this exactly what you need to do http://jsfiddle.net/Aya_Salama/9km5obwa/

Comment: this is a demo for a different approach, so here it removes the current element from the div, appends it to the end and set the next element as the active one
in this case, you don't need to change the margin-left cause you already rearranged your elements so the desired one will be at the beginning, also no need for check if this is the last element or not (cause it will never be). http://jsfiddle.net/Aya_Salama/ajqty6n8/

Comment: that's what I was looking for! Thank you very much!